# Hash of hash is lost when it is out of a subroutine

Tags: perl, hash

I got a problem with hash of hash. I want to create a hash of hash from a foreach loop. I hope I could use the values of the hash of hash outside the foreach loop. However, it seems the hash of hash looks good  inside the foreach loop, but not outside of it. My codes are as below.

```
my(%pother,%pget);

foreach $stn (@stns){
       if (($stn eq 'A')||($stn eq 'B')) {
              &getSomething($stn,\%pother);  #getSomething is a subroutine and it outputs a hash
       }

       $pget{$stn} = \%pother;  # I would like to create a hash of hash

       print map { "$_ => $pget{$stn}{$_}\n" } keys %{$pget{$stn}};  # My 1st print result, which looks good
}

print map { "$_ => $pget{'A'}{$_}\n" } keys %{$pget{'A'}}; # My 2nd print result, which is same as my 3rd one 

print map { "$_ => $pget{'B'}{$_}\n" } keys %{$pget{'B'}}; # My 3rd print result, which is same as my 2nd one
```

The hash of %pother is something like this. The output of %pother will change depends on the $stn

```
%pother = (
    '20200406' => 82,
    '20200405' => 99,
);
```

I want to create a hash of hash like this:

```
$pget = {
          'A' => {
                          '20200406' => 82,
                          '20200405' => 99,
                        },
          'B' => {
                         '20200406' => 97,
                         '20200405' => 67,
                       }
        };
```

However, what I got is as below:

```
$pget = {
          'A' => {
                          '20200406' => 97,
                          '20200405' => 67,
                        },
          'B' => {
                         '20200406' => 97,
                         '20200405' => 67,
                       }
        };
```

I don't know why the 'A' & 'B' became the same when the hash of hash is outside the foreach loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You effectively have the following:

```
my %pother;  # Create a hash.
# ...
$pget{A} = \%pother;
# ...
$pget{B} = \%pother;
# ...
```

So why would you expect `$pget{A}` and `$pget{B}` to be different?

Move `my %pother;` into the loop to create a new hash each loop pass.